# How to separate Socket.IO events from server.js?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I created Express, Node, React app.

Now, i want to integrate socket.io to the app.

I searched all over the internet and i found that all the socket.io events are in the initial server.js/app.js file.

But, i want to separate the socket.io events from the main file and then import it to the main file, just like routes/controllers files.

My code right now:

```
var app = require("express")();
var http = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const stocks = require("./routes/stockRoutes");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const port = 5000;

app.use(stocks);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.set("socketio", io);

const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://admin:admin1234@investockcluster0.jp2wh.mongodb.net/<stocks_data>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose.connect(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

 io.on("connection", (socket) => {
   socket.emit("hello", "world");
   console.log("New Connection");
});

http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

I want that this code will be in file like "socketEvents.js" and then require it.

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
       socket.emit("hello", "world");
       console.log("New Connection");
    });
```

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put your socket.io code in another module and pass in the server in an initialization method:

```
// in sock.js
module.exports = function(server) {

    const io = require("socket.io")(server);
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
       socket.emit("hello", "world");
       console.log("New Connection");
    });

    // put other things that use io here
}
```

Then, in your main file:

```
require('./sock.js')(http);
```

FYI, `http` is a crummy variable name for your server.  You really ought to name it `server`.